# How to add a map in array in firebase firestore in react?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
  addMoreCases = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      makeActive10: false,
      toggleDetails10: true,
    });
    const studentName = this.props.location.state.selectedStudent.basicData
      .studentName;
    var db = fire.firestore();
    const casesObject = this.state.casesObject;
    db.collection("students")
      .where("basicData.studentName", "==", studentName)
      .get()
      .then(function (querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
          console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
          db.collection("students")
            .doc(doc.id)
            // .doc(  )
            .update(
              {
                ...{
                  casesAndAssociatesData: {
                    ...{ casesObject },
                  },
                },
              }

              // { merge: true }
            );
        });
      });
    this.setState({
      casesObject: [
        // { ...initialCasesForm }
        {
          casesPoliceStation: "",
          crimeNumber: "",
          sectionOfLaw: "",
          stage: "",
        },
      ],
    });
  };
                        <Form onSubmit={this.addMoreCases}>
                          <Form.Row key={index}>
                            <Col>
                              <Form.Control
                                style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}
                                type="text"
                                onChange={(e) =>
                                  this.casesObjectUpdate(e, index)
                                }
                                name="casesPoliceStation"
                                placeholder="Police Station"
                                value={cases.casesPoliceStation}
                                onKeyPress={(e) => {
                                  e.key === "Enter" &&
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                }}
                              />
                            </Col>
                            <Col>
                              <Form.Control
                                style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}
                                type="text"
                                onChange={(e) =>
                                  this.casesObjectUpdate(e, index)
                                }
                                name="crimeNumber"
                                placeholder="Crime Number"
                                value={cases.crimeNumber}
                                onKeyPress={(e) => {
                                  e.key === "Enter" &&
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                }}
                              />
                            </Col>
                            <Col>
                              <Form.Control
                                style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}
                                type="text"
                                onChange={(e) =>
                                  this.casesObjectUpdate(e, index)
                                }
                                name="sectionOfLaw"
                                placeholder="Section Of Law"
                                value={cases.sectionOfLaw}
                                onKeyPress={(e) => {
                                  e.key === "Enter" &&
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                }}
                              />
                            </Col>
                            <Col>
                              <Form.Control
                                style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}
                                type="text"
                                onChange={(e) =>
                                  this.casesObjectUpdate(e, index)
                                }
                                name="stage"
                                placeholder="Stage"
                                value={cases.stage}
                                onKeyPress={(e) => {
                                  e.key === "Enter" &&
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                }}
                              />
                            </Col>
                            <Col>
                              <Button
                                type="submit"
                                variant="outline-primary"
                              >
```

Here, in the above code I'm trying to add some more maps in an array using for the specific document ID. So that on button submit, I'm alling function "addMoreCases". And it sould add another map within casesObject array, within casesAndAssociatesData field. I'll be attaching my firestore database image, and in that, within "casesAndAssociatesData" field, within "casesObject" array, I need another map with the form values should be added with the incremented Index[in the above image, if I enter the values in form and hit submit button, I need the values to be added in "casesObject" array with index "2" in "casasAndAssociatesData"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSgUY.png)

Answer (score 0):

[image: and this is my db structure]As far as I understand you have the following structure in your database:

```
collection:
 document:
    casesAndAssociatesData:obj_array
    casesObject:obj_array
```

And you would like to add more data to the `casesObject`. Since  `casesObject` is a filed of the document, you will have to update it every time you add more data.

So the approach would be:

1. Get all the data from the loaded document as an map array.
2. Add another element to that array.
3. Update the entire `casesObject` field with the new data.

This is an example of how you should modify your code:

```
querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {

   console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());

   //Prepare the new data that you want to add :
   var newCasesObject = {
       casesPoliceStation: "New police station Value",
       crimeNumber: "New crime value",
       sectionOfLaw: "New section of law",
       stage: "ss",
   }

   //Get the array with data from the loaded document
   var dataObj = doc.data().casesObject;

   //Push the new data to that array
   dataObj.push(newCasesObject);

   //Call another function that will update the document with the new data
   updateData(doc.id, dataObj);

});

//The new update function:
async function updateData(docID, obj){

   const cityRef = db.collection('[COLLECTION_NAME]').doc(docID);

   // Set the 'capital' field of the city
   const res = await cityRef.update({casesObject: obj});

}
```

I have tested this on my database and it is working as you described. It updates only the field `casesObject` while every time adding a new map data.

Comment: Dear Sir, Thank You. And How to update a specific field within that map?

Comment: You can use `dot notation`  to do so. Please refer to [Update fields in nested objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects) documentation in Cloud Firestore Firebase.

Comment: Dear sir, I did that... But I'm getting error as "
Unhandled Rejection (FirebaseError): Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Nested arrays are not supported"

Comment: And also i have updated the question with an image which has database structure

Comment: Hi, I just tried your solution, to update my values in the database, but I received this error
Nested arrays are not supported was thrown while invoking documentupdate

Can you reply ?